# How do I reload Postgres.app config without restarting?

Tags: postgresql, postgres.app

With a regular postgres install, I would do this either by sending SIGHUP to the postgres process, or by running `pg_ctl reload`. With Postgres.app, however, I'm unsure about where to send SIGHUP (to the Postgres.app process, or one of the workers?), and attempting to run `pg_ctl reload` (after tracking it down to `/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.3/bin` yields only complaints about PG_DATA being unset.

So, how do I reload the configuration files for Postgres.app without restarting the whole server? Is this possible?

Comment: in `psql` run `select pg_reload_conf();` but make sure parameter you are configuring does not require actual restart

Comment: There is now a pretty good documentation site (in 2023) that will show you which changes can be applied when. https://postgresqlco.nf/doc/en/param/max_standby_streaming_delay/

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simplest way: `SELECT pg_reload_conf();`